# Using HtmlParseFilter with Tika parser in Nutch 1.5

Tags: java, nutch

What I'd like to do: write a Nutch plugin that receives the parsed data from every page crawled. I know that `HtmlParseFilter` does what I need for HTML pages, but I also want to process other types of content. When Tika parses, say, a PDF or Word document, would it pass the results to my registered `HtmlParseFilter`? If not, is there any other way to intercept Tika's output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HtmlParseFilter does handle all content types (that Tika can). It has been renamed to ParseFilter in the 2.x branches to more accurately reflect what it does.